# efficient way to apply function to column pairs in the dataframe without loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and lets say shape is 1000x9000.
I want to take each pair of columns (A,B or B,C etc.) and apply a custom function on this vectors (It returns a single value not vector).
In the end I will have square matrix as number of features X features.
**In another way to say, I want to apply custom function before do correlation.** (lets say I have static value "S" and my calculation depends on using A,B columns and "S")
Currently I do that with for loop but it takes time (for 9000 features 72minutes).
Is there any other efficient way to do that?

```
K = len(df.columns)
corrm  = np.empty((K, K), dtype=float)

for i in range(K):
    for j in range(K):
        if i > j:
            continue
        if i == j:
            pass
        else:
            x = df.values[:,i]
            y = df.values[:,j]
            partial_correlation = pcorr(x,y) # returns single value
            corrm[i][j] = partial_correlation
```

example dataframe:

```
            A              B              C            D           E   
sample1 -0.553511498  0.010581301   -0.031557156    0.636841226 -0.034175995
sample2 -0.086819765 -0.008343026   -0.269495143    -1.308358179 -0.944317808
sample3 0.270239413  -0.483162928   -0.062806558    -0.12840758 0.179261486
sample4 0.71904635   1.601002004    1.161017558     0.787858056 1.697507859
sample5 1.388226443  1.450427333    1.401653022     1.682112299 1.352427121
sample6 0.559113914  0.98922773     1.018382478     0.756563628 0.304599497
sample7 0.209627821 -0.145606377    -0.029444883    0.456342405 -0.064318077
sample8 0.355275804  0.485999083     1.515089717    1.462177029 2.530383401
...
```

If I apply correlation function to this dataframe I will have 9000x9000 square matrix.

Comment: Pandas has a built-in way of doing that: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Comment: @NickODell pandas.corr applies general correlation functions I do not want to apply them. Beside the columns I have another variables and I perform correlation using this variables. do you still think it is possible with pandas corr?

Comment: Pandas corr() lets you pass an arbitrary function to define the correlation. So you could use `corr(method=pcorr)`.

Comment: how can I pass to extra argument to that?

Comment: You can define your own lambda and pass a new argument while doing this correlation calculation. e.g. `corr(method=lambda a,b: pcorr(a, b, foo=bar))`